# Make a clip-path inset a square on any viewport, in JS

Tags: javascript, geometry, viewport, clip-path, calc

Hello here is [a codepen](https://codepen.io/eze4fz4e4zegzegzeg/pen/gOELRQB) that shows my problem

I'm trying to make a JS calculation that changes the clip path inset of a div so that it shows a square.
There's one constraint: the square width has to be 20vw

Here is [an image](https://i.ibb.co/zP7y1zp/calculate-clip-path-inset-2.png) that shows how it can look like on different viewports

**I'm just looking for the right calculation based on viewport width/height/ratio**
My brain is freezing :( therefore the current calculation is wrong:

```
const clipPathInset = Math.abs(((0.2 * window.innerWidth) + (ratioDifference * window.innerWidth)) / 100)  

square.style.clipPath = `inset(${clipPathInset}px 40vw)`;
```

Any ideas?
*I'll then readjust the square width with media queries and/or resize event listener*

Answer (score 0):

Somebody commented but the comment isn't there anymore
It was giving a solution that works

```
const squareWidth = 0.2 // equivalent to 20vw
const viewportRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
return window.innerWidth * (1 / viewportRatio - squareWidth) / 2;
```

I don't understand why it works, but it works! Thank you